# Count rows/cases in PSPP

Tags: pspp

I open a .sav file in [PSPP](http://www.gnu.org/software/pspp/) (an open-source alternativ to SPSS) with

> get file=...sav

Now I would like to see how many rows there exist.

Comment: "I cannot guarantee..." sentence is hard to understand. Give more details that would be in line with SPSS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`show n` in regular old SPSS would do what you want. It doesn't appear to be in the [list of commands](http://www.gnu.org/software/pspp/manual/pspp.html#SHOW) for PSPP though.

Another possibility would be to compute your own variable based on the casenumber ($casenum), and then print the maximum casenumber. Something like below would do this.

```
compute #mynumber = $casenum.
freq var #mynumber /format = notable /statistics = maximum.
```

I think you have to have the variable defined before running a frequency (i.e. I don't think you can do `freq var $casenum.`). I don't have PSPP around to check, so let me know if this works in that program.

Comment: 1. "show n" does not work in PSPP,
2. Your code works!
3. "freq var $casenum." does not work as you guessed